# How can I find whether there are any elements at a certain position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I have a collection of divs with the same class at various positions on a larger div. Is there a way, using jQuery, to determine if any divs are overlapping a given position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section on document.elementFromPoint(): http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/more_ie9_goodne.html

You can use this to find the "top-most" element at that location.  Hide that element, then ask again.  If you get another hit, then the 2 divs overlap at that position.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to think this is my only option, but I find it to be quite brittle in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the `offset()` method of JQuery, but the only way to be accurate is to get the offset of *every* element in the document -- not likely to perform well.